# VT100 screen scraping interface for Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo

Hello (also posted on the VWNC list),
We are looking at options for interfacing with a legacy Unix system. One option we'd like to explore would be to screen scrape a VT100 terminal session.

Is there anything out there for Smalltalk VT100 terminal session support, like VA's old EHLLAPI 3270 interface? (worked well for me in an Reuters FX / VA / AS400 system back in '95).

Not had much luck with searches, aside from some very old references to CTermConnection in VW 2.5 and Ian Piumarta's VT102Emulator for Squeak from 2002.
This is a stand alone Seaside app, so any Smalltalk dialect will do.

Thanks for any help,
Bob

Comment: I've never seen any smalltalk for this. But there are plenty of Java, Python, and Perl solutions for this. Would you be up for separating the scraping out into its own web service (in python) and then having your Seaside stuff invoke web methods on the python web service? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Smallalk/X includes both VT52 and VT100 emulators. They are not perfect and do not emulate the whole set of escape sequences, but even if incomplete as-they-are, they may provide something to start with (and extract the stuff which handles the escape sequences).
ST/X can fileout in standard junk format (or fetch the class source from exept's cvs repository)

However, if you run in seaside, I guess you better look for a javascript vt100 emulator and write a seaside widget wrapper for that (which simply pipes through the key-events and incoming data). May be less work in the end, as I assume that JS-emulators are many around.